Isomorphism classes of finite $\mathbb{N}$-groups
Where can I find resources on isomorphism classes of finite $\mathbb{N}$-groups, i.e. groups acted on by the monoid $(\mathbb{N}, +)$?
I edited this question to be more focused on what I'm interested in. I removed a lot of context I gave, but I think I added too much context and it made it hard to understand what I was actually asking for. Hopefully this helps.

I didn’t spot a question in this.

I'm really bad at searching for information online. It's less of a question and more of a reference request asking for where people have looked into this kind of thing. But yea this is not the most well-put-together thing so maybe I should make a dramatic edit of this post to be clearer?

@HJRW hopefully this is better now.

This is a big improvement — thanks! You could include the earlier material after the main question as context, but I think it’s good like this.

I think there are two main ways to see such objects: either as a group together with a chosen endomorphism (which is something you said in an earlier revision, and I think you might have kept that part because it greatly clarifies the notion), which is how most people would see them; or as group objects in the topos of $\mathbb{N}$-sets (which explains why they behave like groups in many ways). That being said, I don't think you can hope for much in way of classification.

@Gro-Tsen Yes, my context said both of those things- in fact, that they are the group objects in that topos is why I became interested in them in the first place. Also, yes, but I assume there might be someone out there who has at least thought about this and done some amount of bookkeeping on what we do know about them.

Quote for posterity: "Here is the background on what groups with operators are, for context. Recall that the category of M-Sets, a chosen monoid M acting on sets with morphisms being M-equivariant maps, is a grothendieck topos by way of being a category of presheaves. Its group objects happen to be groups with operators: a group being acted on by a chosen monoid M." I think in retrospect I should have just assumed the readers here would know what groups with operators are. And this explanation does not much anyway because it's much more abstract than a typical definition.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/476481/automorphisms-of-powers-of-finite-simple-groups I decided to split off a random tangent I had in the original textwall into a separate question.
