Automorphisms of powers of finite simple groups
It is a theorem that a finite nontrivial group $G$ has no proper nontrivial characteristic subgroups if and only if $G \cong S^n$ where $S$ is simple and $n > 0$ is the number of copies of $S$ in a direct product. Call an automorphism $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ irreducible if $\varphi(H) \not\subseteq H$ for all proper nontrivial normal $H \subseteq G$. (I am just coining this term, please let me know if there is an actual name for this.) When $S$ is abelian, irreducible automorphisms are precisely irreps of the group $\mathbb{Z}$ over the vector space $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ and are precisely characterized by irreducible polynomials in the ring $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ of degree $n$, excluding the polynomial $t$ because it corresponds to the $0$ map. What is the situation like when $S$ is non-abelian?
Edit: bolded text added.

So I'm sure this is classical but if $S$ is nonabelian it looks to me like the automorphism group is the wreath product $\text{Aut}(S) \wr S_n$; basically the point is that the obvious copies of $S$ are uniquely determined by some property (e.g. I think they are the only copies of $S$ which are normal, or which are direct summands) so an automorphism has to permute them. Then a necessary condition for irreducibility is that the corresponding permutation of the copies of $S$ is a cycle.

Conversely if the permutation is a cycle then I think $\varphi$ is "indecomposable" in the sense that it doesn't preserve a nontrivial direct summand. This is equivalent to your condition in the abelian case. In the nonabelian case I don't know that irreducibility is a good condition; e.g. if $n = 1$ and $S$ has trivial outer automorphism group then every automorphism of $G$ is inner and so preserves some cyclic subgroup.

Oops, that made me realize an error I made. I should have said that they don't fix normal subgroups.

Suppose $S$ is non-abelian simple. Using https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_subdirect_product_of_perfect_groups_equals_direct_product we know the normal subgroups of $S^n$ are of the form $S^I$ for some subset $I\subset\{1,\dots,n\}$ of indices. So $\varphi$ being irreducible is equivalent to $\varphi(S^I)\not\subset S^I$.
Next, note the following fact that Qiaochu mentions in the comments:
Lemma The automorphism group of $S^n$ is $\mathrm{Aut}(S)\wr \Sigma_n$.
Proof Let $\varphi\colon S^n\to S^n$ be an automorphism. For each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, the $i$-th summand $S_i\subset S^n$ is a normal subgroup, hence $\varphi(S_i)\subset S^n$ is a normal subgroup. But by the above characterization of normal subgroups of $S^n$ we know $\varphi(S_i)=S_{\sigma(i)}$ for some index $\sigma(i)\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. Thus $\varphi=\psi\circ \sigma$ where $\sigma$ permutes the factors and $\psi$ is an automorphism of $S^n$ sending $S_i$ to $S_i$. But then $\psi=\psi_1\times\cdots\times\psi_n$ where $\psi_i\in\mathrm{Aut}(S)$.

Now, let $\varphi\in\mathrm{Aut}(S^n)$ be an automorphism which induces a permutation $\sigma\in \Sigma_n$ on the direct factors. Then the condition that $\varphi(S^I)\not\subset S^I$ is equivalent to $\sigma(I)\not\subset I$ for any non-trivial subset $I$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. This is equivalent to $\sigma$ being a $n$-cycle. Thus, we conclude:
Proposition An automorphism $\varphi$ of $S^n$ is irreducible if and only if the permutation $\sigma\in\Sigma_n$ induced on the direct factors is a $n$-cycle.
